# A portable linux system with luks encryption can't boot on one of my machines

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, encryption, luks

I installed opensuse on a portable SSD drive, which I can boot on several of my machines.

The installation uses luks encryption on /home and /swap partitions (ext4 filesystem).

But only when I use it on my lenovo X1 carbon laptop, after I input the decryption key during boot, it always shows I fail to decrypt the sr_swap partition. I have tried dozens of times on different days with different keyboard but it just doesn't work.

Just to affirm that this portable system can boot fine on my other machines (PC, another lenovo laptop).

Well this is one of the strangest problem I encountered...

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is but I would start by making sure there is no password for it in the BIOS, which seems like the only likely source of problem I can think of if you tried different keyboards.

Comment: What kind of password are you referring to? BIOS does have password but only for BIOS settings. The native system on the laptop is Win10 with Bitlock enabled for its own hard drive.

Comment: What's in the /etc/crypttab? Make sure the partition is referred to by UUID not by something like /dev/sdb2, which may be different on different systems or on same system on different boots.